# The active class does not work in my main menu in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have this html code in my main menu:
**index.html**

```
<nav>
    <ul id="mainmenu" class="nav">
        <li>
            <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#section-services">Services</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

I am trying to add the class "active" to the link of the active menu.

I have tried the following
**functions.php**

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2);
    function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
        if (in_array('current_menu_item', $classes)){
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
return $classes;
}
```

**header.php**

```
<nav>
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
            'theme_location'=> 'top_menu',
            'menu' => 'main-menu',
            'container' => 'nav',
            'menu_id' => 'mainmenu',
                  )
       );
    ?>
</nav>
```

The result is as follows:
[So I don't want it to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHdwi.png)

I want it to appear like this:
[Menu I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIu6Z.png)

Comment: The classes in WP are added to the `li`, not the `a`.

Comment: Yes I understand. But how could I make it add to the `<a>`

Comment: You will need to change/extend the Nav Walker class.

Comment: I'm going to study that @disinfor, thank you very much!